# vecdot generates many allocations when inserting result into an array

Tags: julia

This came up in other, more complex, code but I've written what I think is a minimum working example.

I found this behaviour surprising:

```
function byvecdot!(a,b,c)
    for i in eachindex(a)
        a[i] = vecdot(b[:,i],c[:,i])
    end
    return 
end

function byiteration!(a,b,c)
    for i in eachindex(a)
        a[i] = 0.0
        for j in 1:size(b,1)
            a[i] += b[j,i]*c[j,i]
        end
    end
    return
end

a = zeros(Float64,1000)
b = rand(Float64,1000,1000)
c = rand(Float64,1000,1000)

@time byvecdot!(a,b,c)
fill!(a,0.0) # Just so we have exactly the same environment
@time byiteration!(a,b,c)
```

Results (after warming up the JIT):

```
0.089517 seconds (4.98 k allocations: 15.549 MB, 88.70% gc time)
0.003165 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)
```

I'm more surprised by the number of allocations than the time (the former is surely causing the latter, particularly given all the gc time).

I expected vecdot to be more or less the same as doing it by iteration (with a few extra allocations for length checks etc).

Making this more confusing: when I use vecdot by itself (even on slices/views/subarrays/whatever-they-are-called like b[:,i]), without inserting the result into an array element, it does behave basically the same as by iteration. I looked at the source code in Julia base and, no surprise, vecdot is just iterating over and accumulating up the result.

My question is: Can someone explain to me why vecdot generates so many (unnecessary) allocations when I try to insert it into an array element? What mechanics am I failing to grasp here?

Comment: I should note, I get that 1000 allocations are necessary for the accumulator within vecdot that then gets returned. But what about the other ~4000 allocations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b[:,i]` allocates a new `Array` object so there is a big difference between the two versions. The first version creates many temporaries that the GC will have to track and free. An alternative solution is

```
function byvecdot2!(a,b,c)
    for i in eachindex(a)
        a[i] = vecdot(view(b,:,i),view(c,:,i))
    end
    return 
end
```

The views also allocate but much less than the full copy that `b[:,1]` creates so the GC will do less work.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that makes sense; your example behaves the way I had wanted it to in my mind. I think I must have confused myself into thinking that taking slices always creates views. Thanks for the quick and clear response!